Interpreting Survival function (KAPLAN-MEIER)
Plot survival functions
Hello,
I am currently working on my masters thesis "Buyout contracts and Exit" and due to the nature of my dataset I have to use survival functions because only 32 of the 75 buyouts have exited so far. I am trying to find a relationship between covenants (contractual aspect) and the likelihood of exit.
I hypothese that the presence of transferability covenants will have a higher likelihood of a (sooner) exit.
So the model:
Time variable = Survival_Time (the holding period and for not exited deals it is the current holding period)
Event:Exit (dummy variable indicating 1 if the PE investors have exited) Define event: 1
Factor: Transferability (dummy variabele indicating 1 when there are more than 3 transferability covenants)
Can someone help me with interpreting the plot?
I tried interpreting it but its too complicated? Does it comfirms my hypothesis?
